# Можно ли обойтись только Redis для хранения токенов?

Tags: база-данных, redis, token, authenticationtoken

Кратко о задаче. Я делают бота, который по сути является клиентом к внешнему сервису. И мне ничего не нужно хранить кроме refresh и access токенов для авторизации клиента.
Так вот, могу ли я использовать только Redis или же для надежности лучше использовать какую-нибудь БД, может их стоит использовать всместе, если да, то каким образом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по описанию Redis - оно по умолчанию данные в оперативке хранит, т.е. по дефолту должны теряться все данные при рестарте приложения.

Если это вам не подходит - сохраняйте на диск данные средствами Redis и/или используйте что-то другое.

Answer (score 0):

Редис при правильной настройке, в изолированной среде, например, в одной локальной сети докера, никогда не удалит данные, а будет их дампать локально при перезапуске контейнера или служб.

Comment: Пример такой правильной настройки?

Comment: https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/

Comment: Дока выше, а вот и настройка: appendonly  yes